# How do I get value of the jquery eyecon colorpicker when I hide the colorpicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this color picker http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/.
In this code

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

I cant seem to get the value in the onHide event though I can get it on the other events.How do I get the value at the onHide event?

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me :)

```
 onHide: function (colpkr) {
    hex = "#" + jQuery(colpkr).find('.colorpicker_hex input').val();
 }
```